# rhodes jqtouch jquery HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Tags: jquery, jqtouch, rhodes

I am getting error in my rhodes app .

I/APP     (  379): I 08/19/2011 14:59:45:680 afd4d440      ChromeClientNew| IERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong. -- From line 12 of http://127.0.0.1:8222/public/jqtouch/jquery.1.3.2.min.js

E/Web Console(  379): HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong. at http://127.0.0.1:8222/public/jqtouch/jquery.1.3.2.min.js:12

I am not getting whats wrong.

Because of what it is getting generated?

My controller code, view are running fine when I am trying to invoke them from other place.

all other views are running fine.

my layout.erb file is

```
<% is_bb6 = System::get_property('platform') == 'Blackberry' && (System::get_property('os_version') =~ /^6\.0/) %>

<% if is_bb6 %>  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<% else %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>      
<% end %>

<% if System::get_property('platform') == 'APPLE' || System::get_property('platform') == 'ANDROID' || is_bb6 %>
  <script src="/public/jqtouch/jquery.1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/public/js/rhogeolocation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/public/jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/public/jqtouch/jqtouch.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <% if System::get_property('platform') == 'APPLE' %>
    <link href="/public/jqtouch/jqtouch-iphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <% end %>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> $.jQTouch(); </script>
<% end %>


<% if System::get_property('platform') == 'APPLE' || System::get_property('platform') == 'ANDROID' %>
  <link href="/public/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/retina.css" media="all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
<% elsif is_bb6 %>
  <link href="/public/css/android.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<% elsif System::get_property('platform') == 'Blackberry' %>
  <link href="/public/css/blackberry.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<% else %>
  <link href="/public/css/windows_mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem with a chrome extension when I try to insert a new CSS rule after the page loads.  Interestingly you are running from 127.0.0.1 and I'm running from localhost.  It doesn't happen for me when I'm running outside of localhost.